# How do I delete characters after 10th character from xml tags Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have a xml file with repeated xml tags where I want to trim the string length to 10 characters

Data:

```
<Item>
<ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
<Description>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</Description>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
<Description>Ipsum Lorem</Description>
</Item>
```

Expected Result after trimming `<Description>` tag to 10 character:

```
<Item>
<ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
<Description>Lorem Ipsu</Description>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
<Description>Ipsum Lore</Description>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and enter the following:

- Find what: `(<Description>.{10})(.+?)(</Description>)`
- Replace with: `$1$3`
- Select Regular expression, then click Replace All.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go, without capture groups that slow down the process:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Description>.{10}\K.+?(?=</Description>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Description>           # literally, opening tag
.{10}                   # 10 any character
\K                      # reset match, forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=</Description>)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have the closing tag after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]