# Truncate xml field at 45 characters

Tags: notepad++, xml

This is similar to [How do I delete characters after 10th character from xml tags Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1567614/how-do-i-delete-characters-after-10th-character-from-xml-tags-notepad) but with a different syntax.

Given this data:

```
<I s="FNGU.K" n="Bank of Montreal MicroSectors FANG Index 3X Leveraged ETN Exp 8 Jan 2038" /><I s="FPE" n="First Trust Preferred Securities And Income" />
```

How do I run Notepad++ find and replace with something like

- Find what: `(\s[n]=".{45})(.+?)("\s)` <-- What is the correct regex for my xml example?  It needs to have {45,} or minimum length enforcement somewhere, as otherwise it will do a replace messing up the next element.  Working in regex101.com
- Replace with: `$1$3`

to end up with n never exceeding 45 characters?

```
<I s="FNGU.K" n="Bank of Montreal MicroSectors FANG Index 3X " /><I s="FPE" n="First Trust Preferred Securities And Income" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use the solution provides in duplicate?

Comment: I'm looking for the correct regular expression for my particular xml example..

Comment: Find: `(\sn=".{1,45})[^"]*?("\s)` Replace: `$1$2`